# Translate MySQL join into SQL Server syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In MySQL I used to be able to do something like:

```
SELECT Something1.ID, Something2.AverageValue FROM
(SELECT ID, Max(Date) FROM Table GROUP BY ID) Something1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, AverageValue FROM Table) Something2
ON Something1.ID = Something2.ID
```

So what I am trying to do is give me the most recent averagevalue, per ID

The syntax in SQL Server appears to be different and doesn't allow me to do the nested SELECT statements?

Comment: You have an extra bracket before `ID` I think...

Comment: Thanks, but I presume that doesnt mean I can do the above in SQL Server? I was given the impression the whole syntax for nested joins is different?

Comment: @user1107474: Why not just try it? It should run perfectly well.

Comment: ...except for the fact that `table` is a reserved word and should be delimited with square brackets, but I take it that was just an example

Comment: It says "No column name was specified for column 2 of 'Something 1' and the line of error is actually displayed in red as being  the 'LEFT JOIN', which makes me think it doesnt like the alias name 'Something1'

Comment: No column name means you need to set MAX(Date) AS MaxDate. Also you need to have some date logic in there so that you only show the record that has max date.

Comment: Thanks Cairnz, now I can see the results (because it "compiles") I'll work on that logic- cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH Data AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Row_Number,
 ID,
 AverageValue
 FROM Table
)
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Row_Number = 1
```

This is the way you should do it in SQL Server. It makes "last/first/max/min/greatest-n-per group" easy as pie.

`PARTITION BY` keyword here equals your `GROUP BY` statement, and the `ORDER BY` here would translate into the `MAX` aggregate function you used in MySQL

Using this would enable you to do some fancy stuff like:

```
WITH Data AS
    (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Row_Number,
     ID,
     AverageValue
     FROM Table
    )

SELECT Newest.ID, 
Newest.AverageValue, 
(Newest.AverageValue - Next_Newest.AverageValue) AS AverageValue_Change,
Newest.Date
 FROM Data Newest
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data Next_Newest 
 ON Newest.Row_Number+1 = Next_Newest.Row_Number
AND Newest.ID = Next_Newest.ID 

WHERE Newest.Row_Number=1
```

Comment: Not necessarily *should*, but *could*, yes. Still, the question seems to me more about whether you can join subselects like that or not.

Comment: You can, but why do it like that? :)

Comment: +1 for urging the OP to look for alternative approaches rather than a translation. To employ an analogy, rather than performing a translation of the English words, "Bring home the bacon" into French, one should seek out an equivalent idiom e.g. "Faire bouillir la marmite" ("Keep the pot boiling") ... or get both to speak Esperanto (Standard SQL) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there *is* an issue with this query in SQL Server, as your comment helps to see.

It seems like MySQL is fine about leaving columns represented as expressions, without aliases. This is ‘no can do’ in SQL Server. If a column in the `SELECT` clause is an expression, you *must* provide an alias for it. Therefore:

```
SELECT Something1.ID, Something2.AverageValue FROM
(SELECT ID, Max(Date) AS MaxDate FROM Table GROUP BY ID) Something1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, AverageValue FROM Table) Something2
ON Something1.ID = Something2.ID
```

Since you are not pulling the `MaxDate` column in your main SELECT, you could also just omit it. Anyway, that seems to be the only difference between the two products in this particular case.