# Select the lowest n values from a group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

This is kind of like this questions:

[T-SQL: How to use MIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382384/t-sql-how-to-use-min)

But I want it to return the lowest 4 values per group.

Thank you

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742018/translate-mysql-join-into-sql-server-syntax/8742120#8742120). Just choose the ordering and filter over the ROW_NUMBER. The general tag for this is `greatest-n-per-group` (it doesn't matter if it's least-n-per-group here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT T.*, RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 Order By Col2 ASC)
   FROM dbo.TableName T
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN <= 4
```

[Ranking Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  ID, SomeVal
FROM (
   SELECT ID, SomeVal, row_number() over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY SomeVal ASC) rn
   FROM [TableName]
) T
WHERE rn <= 4
```

This gives you the lowest first 4 `SomeVal` values per `ID`.